# HTML5 Drop Target : In between dragable elements

Tags: html, drag-and-drop

I was following [HTML5 Drop & Drop tutorial](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/) from HTML5 Rocks. However I wanted to drop not on another draggable element, but a dynamically added `div` in between the draggable elements. Here's my **[try](http://jsfiddle.net/TVYvg/)**.

When I hover over the "droppable" divs nothing happens

Also how can I position my dynamically added drop targets so that they dont move my original elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has something to do with event binding to the newly created targets. Check my variant of your code.
http://jsfiddle.net/TVYvg/2/